# How to turn pc in to a cloud server for local network devices

Tags: networking, cloud, local

Is there a software which can help me turn my windows pc in to some kind of a cloud like google drive,so I can have my files on my laptop,while I am at home?

Answer (score 0):

You may look into these cloud server softwares:

- [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org)
- [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com)

As far as I know Windows ist not supported as a host platform for the server software, but you may be able to run it on a Linux VM.